# what is the facebook application ID of the fb app that generates the "Recent Activity" messages on a users profile

Tags: facebook

I think that the "Recent Activity" message sections that get posted on a users facebook profile wall, whenever the user does anything, thereby tracking their every move across the site for all to see, must be put there by a facebook application, albeit one Facebook have created themselves.

A lot of people find these "Recent Activity" messages on their profiles an annoyance, and regularly delete the messages, but its an awful chore to keep up with it.

My idea is that if one could determine the Application ID of the Facebook application that is creating these posts to our profiles, it would be a simple case to "Block" the application and thereafter be freed up from having to do this annoying task. As there doesnt seem to be any other way of stopping this in the facebook account settings. Anyone got any ideas on this? I have tried searching for the application using Facebook search, but not had any luck finding it.

Answer (score 2):

The "recent activity" section is exactly that: your recent activity. It is generated directly by Facebook from actions you have made on the site, not via an app.

Comment: how do you know that? do you have insider information? A lot of the facebook website is actually built from separate facebook applications built on the FB Platform API, Notes, Photos and Videos for example.

Comment: I have no insider information, but logically it does not make sense for it to be an app. The items you mention are indeed official Facebook apps; you can go to the search bar and type their name and it will show up: type "Notes" and you will see a "Notes" item that says "App" underneath, and you can visit the page of each one. The same thing can not be done with "Recent Activity" -- it does not show up as an app in search, nor is there any way to visit some "Recent Activity" app page. It also would not make sense to use a separate app to work with something that is a direct part of Facebook.

Comment: hmm, if you say so, though since when has anything facebook done made sense? j/k

Answer (score 0):

If you do want access the recent activity, officially known as the 'Stream', you can get to it through their API.

You can read more about it here
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

but as Herohtar said there is no App responsible for it, it is core functionality.